# Per request code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, httpcontext

I have a method, that I want to run once per Http request, but after stuff like Context.Current.User has been assigned.

```
    public static void AddPrincipal(HttpContext context)
    {
        var users = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IRepository<User>>();
        var currentUser = users.Retrieve(u => u.Username == context.User.Identity.Name);
        var principal = new Principal(currentUser);
        context.Items.Add("Principal", principal);
    }
```

What's the best way to achieve that in ASP.Net MVC3?

I tried to put it in Controller factory, but I have some partials actions on my pages, so It gets run more that once.

I also tried BeginRequest in Global.asax, but HttpContext.Current.User is null at that point of time..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First I will say that based upon what you are doing, you might want to look more at something like building a custom [MembershipProvider](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider) or at the least a custom [HttpModule](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307996) , but to answer your question:

You might try subscribing to the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` event, which is supposed to be raised after the HttpRequest is finished being authenticated (which should be after the `HttpContext.Current.User` has been populated)

Do something like this in your Global.asax

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddPrinciple(HttpContext.Current);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! just tried that, but for some weird reason HttpContext.Current.User is still null in Application_AuthenticateRequest.. :(

Comment: Have you setup ASP.NET Authentication/Membership? Also is the HttpRequest that you are trying to do this with authenticated?